# Scrollview issue in xml, doesn't work

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview

I have a following code.. I want to scroll my text area and my buttons within in LinearLayout. But my bottom button which is in relativelayout i want to stay it always in bottom not scroll able.
Thanks

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ScrollView 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical">

 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="175dip"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
     <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
             android:textSize="20dip"
              />
     <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
             android:textSize="15dip"
              />
     <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
             android:textSize="15dip"
              />
     <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
             android:textSize="15dip"
              />
     <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
             android:textSize="15dip"
             />
     <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
             android:textSize="15dip"
             />
       <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
             android:textSize="15dip"
             />
       <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
             android:textSize="15dip"
             />
     </RelativeLayout>
     <Button 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         android:text="XYZ"/>
     <Button 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="XYZ"/>
     <Button 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="XYZ"/>
     <Button 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="XYZ"/>
     <Button 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Contact Us"/>


     </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
 <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="50dip"
         android:background="@android:color/black"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
     <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonCheck"
    android:layout_width="50sp"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:text="Checked"  />
     </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try hardcoding height to say 50dpi or so..just to check..

Comment: I tried your xml in my phone and the bottom button do not scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using relative layout, first put the button at the bottom of screen, and then let `scrollview` occupy the the height available.

Try following code:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_btn_Check"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCheck"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:text="Checked" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/rel_btn_Check"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="175dip"
                android:background="@android:color/white" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textSize="20dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                    android:textSize="15dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                    android:textSize="15dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
                    android:textSize="15dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
                    android:textSize="15dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
                    android:textSize="15dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
                    android:textSize="15dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
                    android:textSize="15dip" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="XYZ" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="XYZ" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="XYZ" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="XYZ" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Contact Us" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> use this mechanism
>
> set scroll view >

```
 android:layout_weight="1"
```

and put footer :

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="jgfhrtuioghju oioupotyuhjipouipoi typ[ipo[ip[ijup0[ip0[ujiptjuip[juip[i]]]]]]]      jogi5thjuohuortthjuo90uto     okithjoitthjuo     thjpo     ktjhporyjohj     ptlhjyjohjpy     plthjoyjpokjotjhojuyojuhoithjoi     kgjhoithoithjuotjupojutpo[ujotpotpojuote]ihihoihoi     rguigreuighreiuyghir     orighoihyheiyhreiygh     oighoihtgihidrfyh8irfyhuesghuyhuiehvguyh     rueighuyghuiyghieryhirgeyhi     gorfihoihklrjegoij5oi hi     thkoihioghoirhirhuiurg]     th5yj     u     trjuykyu     yjytku          yktyu     k     ykj     k     y     jiyku          ykj     yuk     yku          k     y     6ty     6y     6yy     kuiil          6     u67     uokityy7     i78o8     "/>
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"><Button android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="rgfjughtih g5yujhoihuoi"/></LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```